# Kafka Cluster Architecture - Mirror Maker

Tags: apache-kafka, mirror, mirroring

I have a Kafka cluster composed by 5 brokers and 4 mirror maker to mirror date from 2 different data centers. I know that a kafka broker requires its own dedicated hardware especially because of the high disk I/O, memory usage and CPU intensive application.

I would like to know if could make sense to deploy a mirror maker process on a node that is even a Kafka broker or if I should consider to have the mirror maker on:

- a dedicated node
- a node which hostes a zookeeper server

HDFS and others cloudera services are deployed on different nodes.

Thanks in advance,
Beniamino

Answer (score 0):

MirrorMaker is just a regular Java Producer/Consumer pair.

If you wrote an application to read from the remote data center, would it make sense to run it on its own hardware? Do you have the resources available to do so? I personally wouldn't run it on a broker or zookeeper.

If you're running in a data center with Docker or Kubernetes available, you can deploy all mirroring instances in their own containers. Or you can run all topics in one JVM using a regex whitelist pattern.

However you choose to deploy, it's recommended to have the consuming process of the MirrorMaker to be in the remote data center pulling data and producing to the local cluster.

[Confluent has discussions about this topic](https://docs.confluent.io/current/multi-dc/index.html)

---

Edit: As of Kafka 2.4, MirrorMaker2 is built on the Kafka Connect framework and is the recommended deployment going forward